# I was once a god. What am I?

Tags: riddle, word

An eternity has passed, but it feels like time has stood still

I killed my true love and my neighbors, but they have not left me

Long ago...

I had the power to raise the seas, and most things you knew and loved

I had the power to destroy you all, but you still managed to step on me

You forgot about me even in your homes, while I stuck around

Your weapons… You lowly, violent humans and your guns --

Their fundamentals managed to kill me

But even in the darkness of death, I am still very much alive

What am I?

Comment: Would it be the moon?

Comment: @Wok exactly my guess. Still some parts don't quite fit well...

Comment: Unfortunately, as was stated, the moon doesn't quite fit.

Comment: While I appreciate the thought behind this one, I feel like the answer got a little vague/muddied - some hints still don't seem to mesh for me. I'd love to see you present more puzzles with the hints a little closer to the mark. Keep up the good work! =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to add another space related answer:

> Black Hole

An eternity has passed

> For a star to become a black hole it has to pass several million years.

I killed my true love and my neighbors, but they have not left me

> This is a story about a solar system and his star. The star become a black hole, and in the process killed his true love, an earth like planet, and the neighbours, the other planets.

I had the power to raise the seas, and most things you knew and loved

> Everything we see here on earth is thanks to the sun. Everything.
>
>  **Edit by @Tosen:** Correction: this explanation does work, however, an expanding star is hot enough to evaporate (raise) just about everything.

I had the power to destroy you all, but you still managed to step on me

> [Sun flares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_flare) can kill us all. And the earth like civilization could somehow step on his star. At night obviously, too hot! No seriously, no clue.
>
>  **Edit by @Tosen:** Correction: Expanding stars destroy everything. Hollywood stars on sidewalks are stepped on.

You forgot about me even in your homes, while I stuck around

> We don't see the sun quite often while we are indoor. Also with artificial light we don't need it, but still it is outside.
>
>  **Edit by @Tosen:** Correction: This is a good explanation. But I was thinking gold "star stickers" that kids are given for good grades.

Your weapons… You lowly, violent humans and your guns --
Their fundamentals managed to kill me

> While trying to harvest solar power the civilization managed to start some kind of destructive process for the star.
>
>  **Edit by @Tosen:** Correction: Ultimately, the depletion of "fusionable" elements (iron!) is what kills a star.

But even in the darkness of death, I am still very much alive

> The black hole still is pumping matter, no signs of ever stop...

Comment: @Tosen Could you please correct the wrong explanations? Edit with no problem the answer, only state were you correct me (i.e leave my answer but add your correct explanation)

Answer (score 3):

Is it:

> The Earth?

An eternity has passed, but it feels like time has stood still

> The earth has been around a long time.

I killed my true love and my neighbors, but they have not left me

> Natural distasters kill many, and comets and other space junk (neighbors) have crashed into the earth, but everything that dies lies in the earth.

Long ago...
I had the power to raise the seas, and most things you knew and loved

> Earthquakes can create tsunamis

I had the power to destroy you all, but you still managed to step on me

> The earth is amazing, but we walk on it every day.

You forgot about me even in your homes, while I stuck around

> We often forget about the earth in what we do, especially at home when we aren't on the "ground," but the earth never moves.

Your weapons… You lowly, violent humans and your guns --
Their fundamentals managed to kill me

> Guns, missles, bombs, etc. have done huge impact on the earth and killed lots of living things.

But even in the darkness of death, I am still very much alive

> Though there are places that seem dead, or we think the earth isn't alive, it is crawling with life.  That, or winter makes everything seem dead when it is really just "sleeping."

Comment: Good guess, but it's not this. The riddle implies that the things that happened "long ago" no longer happen. A few of these things would still happen if it were this.

Comment: She was a god, too: [Gaia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaia_%28mythology%29). The Earth also destroyed its 'true love'; [Theia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theia_%28planet%29).

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> the planet Saturn ?

Reason

> The god Saturn or Cronus was killed by his own children, and some of the moons of planet Saturn are named after the children.

Comment: No, it's not this. The riddle specifically mentions guns and their fundamentals, among other things.

Answer (score 2):

It is a

> Black Dwarf

An eternity has passed

> Black Dwarf is the last stage of a star.

I killed my true love and my neighbors, but they have not left me

> As a star, at the end of your life you started expanding, then absorbed all the planets orbiting around you.

I had the power to raise the seas, and most things you knew and loved

> The gravity was strong in you!

I had the power to destroy you all, but you still managed to step on me

> An advanced civilization with extreme technologies managed to step on your surface.

You forgot about me even in your homes, while I stuck around

> It was night.

Your weapons… You lowly, violent humans and your guns --
Their fundamentals managed to kill me

> Something went wrong during an experiment...

But even in the darkness of death, I am still very much alive

> You're black, invisible in the darkness, but you're still there.

Comment: +1. The explanations are a little off, but this does fit. If no one else comes up with a more accurate end result (yours is a tiny bit off), then I'll accept this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it is

> the Moon

Reason

> We have stepped on it (despite various conspiracy theories), it is supposed to have its origin in the collision between a primitive Earth and an incoming planet/asteroid (it "killed" its "neighbor", but its successor stayed) , it affects the sea tides...

How close am I? :)

Comment: Spaced themed answers seem to be the norm with this question, however this answer is incorrect. Specifically, it doesn't answer the last few lines.